# how to let aufs use more than 127 layers? or an alternative to it

Tags: limit, aufs

I came to the conclusion that aufs is limited to 127 layers based on tests.

**(prepare)**

```
mkdir write joined {1..400}
for((i=1;i<=400;i++));do echo >$i/$i.txt;done #for checks
```

**using a single mount, the limit is 84 layers (numbereds + the write one).**

The folder name doesn't change the 84 limit (so each could be bigger ex. "layer-72", therefore not a string size limitation).

```
sudo mount -v -t aufs \
  -o "sync,br=write:1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:10:11:12:13:14:15:16:17:18:19:20:21:22:23:24:25:26:27:28:29:30:31:32:33:34:35:36:37:38:39:40:41:42:43:44:45:46:47:48:49:50:51:52:53:54:55:56:57:58:59:60:61:62:63:64:65:66:67:68:69:70:71:72:73:74:75:76:77:78:79:80:81:82:83:84" \
  "none" "joined";echo $?
```

The above will fail, unless you remove ":84" from the end.

**Using remount, it can go up to 127 layers (numbereds + the write one)**

```
sudo mount -v -t aufs -o "sync,br=write" "none" "joined";echo $?
for((i=1;i<=400;i++));do 
  echo "try $i";
  if ! "sudo" "mount" -v "-o" "remount,append:$i" "joined";then
    break; # it stops with error "No space left on device", but is not related to free bytes on storage!
  fi;
  ls -l joined/$i.txt;
done
```

**research**

I am trying to use `mount.aufs` just to see readable error messages, as `mount -v` is not helping.

Is there documentation specifying how to translate `mount` parameters to `mount.aufs`?

I am still trying to find `mount.aufs` source code too; that could help my understanding of what parameters it accepts.

**Alternative acceptable answer**

Is aufs patchable (as apparently 127 is a hard-coded limit)? Is it worth the effort/mess, or more than 127 may cause performance issues as suggested on comments?

Could an alternative folders merger provide more than 127 layers? If so, which one? Here a list I found: overlayfs unionfs mhddfs mergerfs docker. What commands I should use based on the test case I provided above? aufs is quite clear and simple to use and understand, and that was the main reason I chose it.

PS.: I am using this now: [how to make mergerfs behave like I did aufs behave: only write everything new or modified (including paths, everything..) to a single writable folder?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/704168/how-to-make-mergerfs-behave-like-i-did-aufs-behave-only-write-everything-new-or/730165#730165)

Comment: Why do you need 83 layers?

Comment: @StephenKitt later I need about 300 layers, but currently I am aiming at +-120 layers. It is a good way to install modifications without dropping the files directly on the same main/target folder, so each modification has it's own folder making it a lot easy to uninstall it, and the target is the merged thru aufs

Comment: Likely using some sort of source code control system will be far easier than managing aufs like this. Also each layer of aufs adds additional overhead. I guess if your file access is minimal or you have many free/fast CPUs with no work to do... you'll be okay. My guess is eventually this approach will create many problems over time.

Comment: @DavidFavor I only actually need the final merged one for read-only, but if anything minimal is written (usually logs and config files), it goes to the `write` layer. It is mainly to keep it organized and easy to maintain.

Comment: @AquariusPower AUFS has a hard limit of 127 layers. You won't be able to exceed that without changing the underlying filesystem. I don't know if OverlayFS has a higher limit, but the latter has the slight advantage of being included in mainline Linux. Or, Docker likes devicemapper